# Update the phone number after adding formatting in Oracle database

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a table say Employee with a column as phone_number. Currently the phone number is added as text say  123456789. I want to update the data with format as : 123 456 789.
i.e. from 9 digit phone number to String of 3digits1space3digits1space3digits.

I am using `REGEXP_REPLACE(phone_number, '\d{3}\s{1}\d{3}\s{1}\d{3}')` which is not working.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest doing this the easy way:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEES
  SET PHONE_NUMBER = SUBSTR(PHONE_NUMBER, 1, 3) || ' ' ||
                     SUBSTR(PHONE_NUMBER, 4, 3) || ' ' ||
                     SUBSTR(PHONE_NUMBER, 7, 3)
  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(PHONE_NUMBER, '\d{9}')
```

Regular expressions have their place - but their place is not everyplace. :-)

Best of luck.